# pandas: saving data frame to dict in correct time format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want the following output from my pandas dataframe df:

```
{1622564509268542720: '36.15', 1622564509311439360: '37.83', 1622564509312406784: '38.20', 1622564509357944832: '40.40', 1622564509358921984: '33.46', 1622564509404489472: '38.37', 1622564509405471232: '37.15'}
```

When i type `df.head(3).to_dict()`, it outputs in the following format

```
{'ApparentPower': {Timestamp('2021-06-01 16:21:50.754080768'): 40.83, Timestamp('2021-06-01 16:21:50.755921664'): 106.41, Timestamp('2021-06-01 16:21:50.800695808'): 46.56}}
```

Whats the easiest way to get it into the format i need above?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a small sample of dataframe and corresponding expected output for the given sample and make sure to include the code that you have tried so far. Looking at your present question the input and output dictionaries don't relate.with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the index to integer:

```
df.set_index(df.index.astype(int))['ApparentPower'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1622564510754080768: 40.83,
 1622564510755921664: 106.41,
 1622564510800695808: 46.56}
```